# Shorten text without splitting words or breaking html tags

Tags: php

I am trying to cut off text after 236 chars without cutting words in half and preserving html tags. This is what I am using right now:

```
$shortdesc = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description');
$lenght = 236;
echo substr($shortdesc, 0, strrpos(substr($shortdesc, 0, $lenght), " "));
```

While this is working in most cases, it won't respect html tags. So for example this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <strong>Stet clita kasd gubergren</strong>
```

will get cut off with the  tag still being open. Is there any way to cut off text after 236 chars but respecting html tags?

Comment: What is the expected output ? If you want only text you could strip html tags ...

Comment: You would have to use an [HTML parser[(http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this and count all the characters in textnode for this.

Comment: Remove the tags entirely? `preg_replace ("<[^>]*>", "", $shortdesc)`

Comment: Google is a wonderful thing http://alanwhipple.com/2011/05/25/php-truncate-string-preserving-html-tags-words/

Comment: Try using [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split text by tagged content.

Comment: @wau There is [strip_tags](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for that :p

Comment: @wau that is not respecting tags

Comment: I have a solution here, but it is a monster, which uses preg_split and preg_match to find open and close tags and keeps track of these, then closes the open ones at the end.

Comment: I was using the function that @fullybaked mentioned until i found [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Truncate your text as you wish and use HTMLPurifier to correct closing missing tags.

Comment: Try This Link, May help You
  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 19):

Best solution I have come across for this is from the CakePHP framework TextHelper class

Here is the method

```
/**
* Truncates text.
*
* Cuts a string to the length of $length and replaces the last characters
* with the ending if the text is longer than length.
*
* ### Options:
*
* - `ending` Will be used as Ending and appended to the trimmed string
* - `exact` If false, $text will not be cut mid-word
* - `html` If true, HTML tags would be handled correctly
*
* @param string  $text String to truncate.
* @param integer $length Length of returned string, including ellipsis.
* @param array $options An array of html attributes and options.
* @return string Trimmed string.
* @access public
* @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/1469/Text#truncate-1625
*/
function truncate($text, $length = 100, $options = array()) {
    $default = array(
        'ending' => '...', 'exact' => true, 'html' => false
    );
    $options = array_merge($default, $options);
    extract($options);

    if ($html) {
        if (mb_strlen(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $text)) <= $length) {
            return $text;
        }
        $totalLength = mb_strlen(strip_tags($ending));
        $openTags = array();
        $truncate = '';

        preg_match_all('/(<\/?([\w+]+)[^>]*>)?([^<>]*)/', $text, $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if (!preg_match('/img|br|input|hr|area|base|basefont|col|frame|isindex|link|meta|param/s', $tag[2])) {
                if (preg_match('/<[\w]+[^>]*>/s', $tag[0])) {
                    array_unshift($openTags, $tag[2]);
                } else if (preg_match('/<\/([\w]+)[^>]*>/s', $tag[0], $closeTag)) {
                    $pos = array_search($closeTag[1], $openTags);
                    if ($pos !== false) {
                        array_splice($openTags, $pos, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            $truncate .= $tag[1];

            $contentLength = mb_strlen(preg_replace('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|&#x[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', ' ', $tag[3]));
            if ($contentLength + $totalLength > $length) {
                $left = $length - $totalLength;
                $entitiesLength = 0;
                if (preg_match_all('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|&#x[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', $tag[3], $entities, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                    foreach ($entities[0] as $entity) {
                        if ($entity[1] + 1 - $entitiesLength <= $left) {
                            $left--;
                            $entitiesLength += mb_strlen($entity[0]);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $truncate .= mb_substr($tag[3], 0 , $left + $entitiesLength);
                break;
            } else {
                $truncate .= $tag[3];
                $totalLength += $contentLength;
            }
            if ($totalLength >= $length) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (mb_strlen($text) <= $length) {
            return $text;
        } else {
            $truncate = mb_substr($text, 0, $length - mb_strlen($ending));
        }
    }
    if (!$exact) {
        $spacepos = mb_strrpos($truncate, ' ');
        if (isset($spacepos)) {
            if ($html) {
                $bits = mb_substr($truncate, $spacepos);
                preg_match_all('/<\/([a-z]+)>/', $bits, $droppedTags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                if (!empty($droppedTags)) {
                    foreach ($droppedTags as $closingTag) {
                        if (!in_array($closingTag[1], $openTags)) {
                            array_unshift($openTags, $closingTag[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $truncate = mb_substr($truncate, 0, $spacepos);
        }
    }
    $truncate .= $ending;

    if ($html) {
        foreach ($openTags as $tag) {
            $truncate .= '</'.$tag.'>';
        }
    }

    return $truncate;
}
```

Other frameworks may have similar (or different) solutions to this problem, so you could take a look at them too.  My familiarity with Cake is what prompted my linking to their solution

Edit:

Just tested this method in an app I'm working on with the OP's text

```
<?php 
echo truncate(
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <strong>Stet clita kasd gubergren</strong>', 
236, 
array('html' => true, 'ending' => '')); 
?>
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <strong>Stet clita kasd gubegre</strong>
```

Notice the output stops just short of completing the last word, but includes the complete strong tags

Comment: It is a good function, but I think the CakePHP-Funktion is meant for truncating stuff written to the DB, not a text which contains a lot of entities, i.e. it truncates the representation not the visible characters in the HTML output the user sees. Unless it did change in the meantime where I looked last at it.

Comment: @Adder this method is from the TextHelper used in views and has nothing (really) to do with the DB.  It is for exactly the use case in the original question.

Comment: This looks really promising, but here is what happens to my <strong> tag in the given example:
    <stro... div="" <="">

Comment: @fullybaked: I know this function and it has problems with text that contains many HTML-Entites. The trouble starts with that that it determines the length of the representation, not the displayed characters. If it is meant for Views, it doesn't work when the text contains e.g. &quot; or &#5050;

Comment: @loeffel: you need to switch on the html mode by providing an options array with html true: `truncate($text, 40, array('html'=>true))`

Comment: See my edits with examples running your text through the method in a CakePHP app I'm working on right now and using this method

Comment: @Adder just FYI I've tested that method again as I'd never come across your stated issues. Using both `&quote;` and `&#5050;` in a string, along with some other entities, the function continued to work as expected.

Comment: Try a text with 10 russian characters encoded as e.g. &#1041; each and truncate it at 20 characters and use the standard ending '..' and html mode and truncate exact, and you will not get just the same 10 russian characters.

Comment: @Adder but is that more to do with PHP's issues with unicode when dealing with its native strings? than anything specifically wrong with this function.  If multi-byte unicode characters are required, then something that can handle them specifically would be needed, but that could be added to this method

Comment: The function indeed works well on normal Unicode text, it just doesn't handle html entities correctly. This is a problem if you applied htmlspecialschars or filter_input/filter_var on the input for security reasons. And yes, my version of truncate is heavily modified to work with entities.

Answer (score 18):

This should do it:

```
class Html
{
    protected
        $reachedLimit = false,
        $totalLen = 0,
        $maxLen = 25,
        $toRemove = array();

    public static function trim($html, $maxLen = 25)
    {

        $dom = new DomDocument();

        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0) {
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
        } else {
            $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        }

        $instance = new static();
        $toRemove = $instance->walk($dom, $maxLen);

        // remove any nodes that exceed limit
        foreach ($toRemove as $child) {
            $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
        }

        // remove wrapper tags added by DD (doctype, html...)
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0) {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6953808/1058140
            $dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);
            $dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);

            return $dom->saveHTML();
        }

        return $dom->saveHTML();
    }

    protected function walk(DomNode $node, $maxLen)
    {

        if ($this->reachedLimit) {
            $this->toRemove[] = $node;
        } else {
            // only text nodes should have text,
            // so do the splitting here
            if ($node instanceof DomText) {
                $this->totalLen += $nodeLen = strlen($node->nodeValue);

                // use mb_strlen / mb_substr for UTF-8 support
                if ($this->totalLen > $maxLen) {
                    $node->nodeValue = substr($node->nodeValue, 0, $nodeLen - ($this->totalLen - $maxLen)) . '...';
                    $this->reachedLimit = true;
                }
            }

            // if node has children, walk its child elements
            if (isset($node->childNodes)) {
                foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                    $this->walk($child, $maxLen);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->toRemove;
    }
}
```

Use like: `$str = Html::trim($str, 236);`

[(demo here)](https://3v4l.org/sGcfG)

---

#### Some performance comparisons between this and cakePHP's regex solution

[image]

There's very little difference, and at very large string sizes, DomDocument is actually faster. Reliability is more important than saving a few microseconds in my opinion.

Comment: This  didn't work for me.

I had to change `if(isset($node->childNodes))` to `if ( $node->hasChildNodes())`

Comment: Did not work for Unicode for me, even when using mb_strlen() / mb_substr() as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Can I just give a thought ?

Sample text :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <i class="red">magna aliquyam erat</i>, duo dolores et ea rebum. <strong>Stet clita kasd gubergren</strong> hello
```

First, parse it into:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'tag' => '',
        'text' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, '
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'tag' => '<i class="red">',
        'text' => 'magna aliquyam erat',
    )
    '2' => ......
    '3' => ......
)
```

then cut the text one by one, and wrap each one with its tag after cut,

then join them.

Comment: @PeeHaa 埽 of course you can use the similiar method to deal with nested tags, but you didn't say you need deal with nested tags in your question

Comment: Not my question. But my experience is when working on stuff like this always keep in mind stuff like nesting beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with Unicode (from [@nice ass answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16584383/13771052)):

```
class Html
{
    protected
        $reachedLimit = false,
        $totalLen = 0,
        $maxLen = 25,
        $toRemove = [];

    public static function trim($html, $maxLen = 25)
    {

        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

        $instance = new static();
        $toRemove = $instance->walk($dom, $maxLen);

        // remove any nodes that exceed limit
        foreach ($toRemove as $child) {
            $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
        }

        return $dom->saveHTML();
    }

    protected function walk(\DOMNode $node, $maxLen)
    {

        if ($this->reachedLimit) {
            $this->toRemove[] = $node;
        } else {
            // only text nodes should have text,
            // so do the splitting here
            if ($node instanceof \DOMText) {
                $this->totalLen += $nodeLen = mb_strlen($node->nodeValue);

                // use mb_strlen / mb_substr for UTF-8 support
                if ($this->totalLen > $maxLen) {
                    dump($node->nodeValue);
                    $node->nodeValue = mb_substr($node->nodeValue, 0, $nodeLen - ($this->totalLen - $maxLen)) . '...';
                    $this->reachedLimit = true;
                }
            }

            // if node has children, walk its child elements
            if (isset($node->childNodes)) {
                foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                    $this->walk($child, $maxLen);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->toRemove;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more detail in your answer by explaining why and how it will work.

Comment: This is the same solution as described above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16584383/13771052

But I added the handling of Unicode with `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

Comment: It would be better to comment your update on the answer for the author to edit into theirs, or at least give credit to the answer you've updated.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do at beginning, but I don't have enough "reputation" to comment his post :-( But I will give credits to him as soon as I get how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

```
function limitStrlen($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true, $skip_html) 
{
    // strip tags, if desired
    if ($strip_html || !$skip_html) 
    {
        $input = strip_tags($input);

        // no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
        if (strlen($input) <= $length) 
        {
            return $input;
        }

        //find last space within length
        $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
        if($last_space !== false) 
        {
            $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $length);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (strlen(strip_tags($input)) <= $length) 
        {
            return $input;
        }

        $trimmed_text = $input;

        $last_space = $length + 1;

        while(true)
        {
            $last_space = strrpos($trimmed_text, ' ');

            if($last_space !== false) 
            {
                $trimmed_text = substr($trimmed_text, 0, $last_space);

                if (strlen(strip_tags($trimmed_text)) <= $length) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $trimmed_text = substr($trimmed_text, 0, $length);
                break;
            }
        }

        // close unclosed tags.
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($trimmed_text);
        $trimmed_text = $doc->saveHTML();
    }

    // add ellipses (...)
    if ($ellipses) 
    {
        $trimmed_text .= '...';
    }

    return $trimmed_text;
}

$str = "<h1><strong><span>Lorem</span></strong> <i>ipsum</i> <p class='some-class'>dolor</p> sit amet, consetetur.</h1>";

// view the HTML
echo htmlentities(limitStrlen($str, 22, false, false, true), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

// view the result
echo limitStrlen($str, 22, false, false, true);
```

**Note:** There may be a better way to close tags instead of using `DOMDocument`. For example we can use a `p tag` inside a `h1 tag` and it still will work. But in this case the heading tag will close before the `p tag` because theoretically it's not possible to use `p tag` inside it. So, be careful for HTML's strict standards.

Answer (score -2):

You can take an XML approach and push elements to a string var until the length of the string exceed 236

example code ?

```
for each node // text or tag
  push to the string var

  if string length > 236
    break

endfor
```

for parsing HTML in PHP http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -2):

I did in JS, hope this logic will help in PHP too..

```
splitText : function(content, count){
        var originalContent = content;
         content = content.substring(0, count);
          //If there is no occurance of matches before breaking point and the hit breakes in between html tags.
         if (content.lastIndexOf("<") > content.lastIndexOf(">")){
            content = content.substring(0, content.lastIndexOf('<'));
            count = content.length;
            if(originalContent.indexOf("</", count)!=-1){
                content += originalContent.substring(count, originalContent.indexOf('>', originalContent.indexOf("</", count))+1);
            }else{
                 content += originalContent.substring(count, originalContent.indexOf('>', count)+1);
            }
          //If the breaking point is in between tags.
         }else if(content.lastIndexOf("<") != content.lastIndexOf("</")){
            content = originalContent.substring(0, originalContent.indexOf('>', count)+1);
         }
        return content;
    },
```

Hope this logic helps some one..

Answer (score -2):

Here is JS solution: [trim-html](https://github.com/brankosekulic/trimHtml)

The idea is to split HTML string in that way to have an array with elements being html tag(open or closed) or just string.

```
var arr = html.replace(/</g, "\n<")
              .replace(/>/g, ">\n")
              .replace(/\n\n/g, "\n")
              .replace(/^\n/g, "")
              .replace(/\n$/g, "")
              .split("\n");
```

Than we can iterate through array and count characters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MathiasMüller thanks for suggestion, I think the code is to big to paste here, I added the idea behind it.