# How can I limit an html texts with some character count?

Tags: php, html

I have a blog post content in HTML. I want to display only 25 words in posts list.

When I used this code I get some errors because of tag-closings.

```
function str_limit_word($text, $limit, $ending = '...') {
    if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
        $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . $ending;
    }
    return $text;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Mind sharing the error

Comment: `<a href="http://ozankurt... </p>` and so on

Comment: Please edit your question and be to the point what do you experience

Comment: use `$text = strip_tags($text);` before you start manipulating the string. That removes the HTML from the text, otherwise you will most likely get invalid HTML back (plus that a bunch of the 25 chars will be tags and not text)

Comment: You need to create a dom partial and remove child elements or not allow html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorten text without splitting words or breaking html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583676/shorten-text-without-splitting-words-or-breaking-html-tags)

Comment: strip_tags worked just fine thanks!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you please write that as an answer?

Comment: seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583676/shorten-text-without-splitting-words-or-breaking-html-tags .

Comment: this question was asked and responded 2 years ago, what is wrong with you...

Comment: Much is wrong with everyone. However; when I search for stuff and find duplicates in that search, I mark them as such so items can be grouped by automated processes .

Comment: There is already a solution here, people can get their excepted results by checking the answers. Don't make them waste more them as they should, by directing them to new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$text = strip_tags($text);` before you start manipulating the string. That removes the HTML from the text, otherwise you will most likely get invalid HTML back if it happens to truncate the text in the middle of a tag, and any HTML-attributes will also be counted in the string length.

Like this:

```
function str_limit_word($text, $limit, $ending = '...') {
    // Remove any HTML tag in the string.
    $text = strip_tags($text); 

    if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
        $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . $ending;
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
       function character_limiter($text, $limit, $start = 0) {
       if(strlen($text) > strlen($limit))
            return substr($text, $start, $limit) . '...';
        else 
            return $text;
      }
```

Comment: it does not limit on _words_ ?