# PHP strip MySQL echo column

Tags: php, mysql

Using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259689/split-a-text-into-two-columns-with-php), I'm experimenting with substr and strrpos and just cannot seem to get it right.

I have a name column coming from a MySQL database that contains both first and last name like this:

```
Doe, Jane A
```

The existing PHP echo looks like:

```
<?php echo($row_WADACustomerInfo['BillingName']); ?>
```

How do I strip the BillingName to only show Jane (firstname)?

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? You want to be able to remove the "Doe," and the "A"?

Comment: `list($surname, $forename) = explode(',', $row_WADACustomerInfo['BillingName']);` would be a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the last name, then the following works:

```
$explodeName = explode(',', $row_WADACustomerInfo['BillingName']);
$firstName = trim(array_pop($explodeName));
echo $firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use regular expression to locate the first name:

```
preg_match("/(\w+), (\w+)/", $row_WADACustomerInfo['BillingName'], $results);
echo $results[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the full name contains three parts separated by a space ("Doe", "Jane,", and "A"), let's explode the variable to make an array. Then we take the second part as the first name. As arrays are indexed from zero, this would be the item number 1. So:

```
$aFullName = explode(" ", $row_WADACustomerInfo['BillingName']);
$firstName = $aFullName[1];
echo $firstName;
```

Comment: Please explain how your solution solves the problem to help future visitors to this question better understand.